# How to buy specific amount of a token

Tags: web3.py, python, bsc, pancakeswap

I wrote a script that buys with the specified amount of BNB, but now I want to buy with the specific amount of the token I wish to buy.
Here is my code

```
def Buy():


    #tokenAddress =input("\n Enter Token address you want to buy: ")
    tokenAddress="0x78867BbEeF44f2326bF8DDd1941a4439382EF2A7"


    getTokenName = web3.eth.contract(address=tokenAddress,
                                     abi=tokenNameABI)
    tokenSymbol = getTokenName.functions.symbol().call()
    decimals = getTokenName.functions.decimals().call()
    Decimals = 10 ** decimals
    print("\nTrying to buy... ", tokenSymbol)


    tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress(tokenAddress)
    spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd")  # wbnb contract address

    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress)
    pancakeswap2_txn = contractbuy.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
        
        0,  # tokenB,
        [spend, tokenToBuy],
        walletAddress,
        (int(time.time()) + 10000)
    ).buildTransaction({

        'from': walletAddress,
        'value': web3.toWei(0.001, 'ether'),
        
        
        'gas': 300000,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('50', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress),
    })
    # Sign transaction with priavte key here
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, config.private)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    print("Snipe was succesfull, bought: ", 'https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/' + web3.toHex(tx_token))
    #print(web3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(web3.toHex(tx_token)))
    exit() ``
```

Comment: Look for the function `swapETHForExactTokens`.

Comment: yout answer is not specific i already looked it up

Answer (score 0):

tokenA : Token I am trying to sell

tokenB : BNB token to convert after sale

Here is how I succeeded. I focused on getting the output amount giving a certain input amount of tokenA.

For this I have to first get the decimals of the tokenA and then equate my desired value to match with the required decimal places. String formatting helped in getting exact number instead of number with power eg 10**18 instead you want your code to read this 1000000000000000000.

```
decimals = getTokenName.functions.decimals().call()
DECIMAL = 10 ** decimals
minimum_amount= 2 * Decimals
minimum_amount='{:.0f}'.format(minimum_amount)
value = contractbuy.functions.getAmountsOut(int(minimum_amount),
                                                 [web3.toChecksumAddress(bUsdAddress),
                                                  web3.toChecksumAddress(bBnbAdress)]).call() 

buyingamountinBNB = value[1] / 10 ** 18)
```

''''''

Comment: [Here is a library that can help you to buy tokens from Uniswap v2 like exchanges](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/eth-hentai).